# Bend Cube by video dont work

Tags: mesh

based on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq2_goboheo&t=206s
I tried to bend cube. [image]

but this comes out. I tried many times.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the walls of the cube that are going to be bent are not subdivided enough. Bending will not generate new geometry, but rather just moves what’s there. You need to subdivide the edges that are intended to turn into curved surfaces.